# multiple form with single submit button to retrieve value of fields within bith form

Tags: php, html, forms

```
index.php
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitForms()
            {
                document.forms["form-1"].submit();
                document.forms["form-2"].submit();
            }
        </script>
        </head>
            <body>
                <form method="POST" action="form.php" id='form-1'>
                    <input type="text" name="txt1" />
                </form>
                <form method="POST" action="form.php" id='form-2'>
                    <input type="text" name="txt2" />
                </form>
                <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="submitForms();" />
            </body>
</html>

form.php
    <?php
        echo $_POST['txt1'];
        echo $_POST['txt2'];
    ?>
```

Above is my code and when i submit both forms then both text-fields with their value it does not shoe me both text-field values.It only shoe me second text-field value.Please help me quickly.

Comment: Why should you have two forms?

Answer (score 1):

I think because you try to get the params after sumbit two forms. You have sent the two forms at once and the second has stepped to the first, so the result is the return of the second form.

I think this will be better:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="form.php">
            <input type="text" name="txt1" />
            <input type="text" name="txt2" />
            <input type="submit" value="Click Me!" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>


<?php
    echo $_POST['txt1'];
    echo $_POST['txt2'];
?>
```

Sorry for my english

Comment: I want two forms and each one has its own fields with single submit button.You had suggested an easy way which is i already know.

Comment: If you do this on your function, you launch two forms, i mean, it go two times to form.php. First time with the text1 param but you submit the other form instantelly and this interrupt the first submit form for doing second form with the text2 param. Because of this, you only show last param (text2).

Comment: ok but is there any way to do this which i am working because i need that kind of task to do.

Comment: ok. Yo need two forms with input txt1 in one and input txt2 in the other. But why you need to submit this two forms? Think that the second submit stops the excecution of first. Can you give me more information about the application you want to do? Or the exercise? Thanks :)